# Setting VPN to go through certain IPs and not others

Tags: windows, vpn, ip, routing

I'm a scientific programmer with a loose grasp of what goes on under the hood in my small home network so bear with me whilst I try and explain using the correct words if possible.

My home network of five PCs (Windows 7, Vista, 2003, 2 x XP) uses the `192.168.0.0` range of IP addresses.  My ADSL router is `192.168.0.1` and is set to do DHCP and all that good stuff.  So far, so good.  Most importantly I can connect to my local web server on `192.168.0.42`.

I frequently have to connect up to a client's VPN using Checkpoint SecureClient.  When I do so I'm given a `10.something` IP address on the 'virtual' network card.

If I'm connected to the VPN I can no longer connect to my `192.168.0.42` web server.

**How can I tell my PCs to *only* go via the VPN for anything beginning `10.*` and to stay 'local' for everything else?**

(below added following Chris Thorpe's answer)

BTW I don't see the VPN connection under Control Panel.  I just see my physical NIC.  Here's what I see running `ipconfig`, if that helps:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection* 6:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : <removed for security!> 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.14.2.130
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.128
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.101
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

(another edit following gravyface's response)

A route print gives 50+ lines of routing info.  Here's some lines if that helps...

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 11 ...54 ec 6d 95 66 05 ...... Check Point Virtual Network Adapter For SecureClient

  8 ...00 19 d1 6a 79 cb ...... Intel(R) 82566DC Gigabit Network Connection

  1 ........................... Software Loopback Interface 1

===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.101     10
         10.0.2.0    255.255.255.0      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
         10.1.0.0      255.255.0.0      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
         10.2.0.0      255.254.0.0      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
         10.4.0.0      255.255.0.0      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1

<lots of 10.*  removed>
<some seemingly random IP addresses removed until we get to the 192.168 >

      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.101    266
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
    192.168.0.101  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.101    266
    192.168.0.101  255.255.255.255      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.101    266
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
      192.168.4.0    255.255.255.0      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
     192.168.16.0    255.255.255.0      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
     192.168.64.0    255.255.255.0      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
     192.168.67.0    255.255.255.0      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
    192.168.120.0    255.255.255.0      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
    192.168.125.0    255.255.255.0      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
    192.168.140.0    255.255.255.0      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
    192.168.150.0    255.255.255.0      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
    192.168.250.3  255.255.255.255      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
    192.168.250.8  255.255.255.254      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
    192.168.253.1  255.255.255.255      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
    192.168.253.2  255.255.255.255      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
    192.168.254.3  255.255.255.255      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
    192.168.254.8  255.255.255.254      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
   192.168.254.10  255.255.255.255      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
    192.168.255.1  255.255.255.255      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1
    192.168.255.2  255.255.255.255      10.14.2.129      10.14.2.130      1

<some other non 192.168* removed>

  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       10.14.2.130    256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.101    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Answer (score 3):

Go into:

1. Control Panel -> Network Connections -> find your VPN connection
2. Right-click it and select properties.
3. Find the TCP/IP settings and then the 'advanced' settings pane.
4. Untick 'use default gateway on remote network'

Answer (score 1):

The CheckPoint VPN client should be doing split tunneling by default, that is, there will be a route (you can run `print route` to see what I mean) that directs all traffic destined to the 10.0 subnet to your VPN interface/gateway.  If it isn't then you can uncheck it:
right-click Systray icon > Settings >  Properties of your profile > Advanced tab > "Route all traffic through gateway" or something like that and uncheck it.

What this means is that you shouldn't have any problems getting to your webserver *by IP* but perhaps the CheckPoint is changing your DNS settings?  Do you have a DNS server running? i.e. do you normally access your webserver via IP (http://192.168.0.42) or DNS?