# Why does routing for this single address fails?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

**Summary**: I would like to route traffic initiated from a specific IP to a VPN

**Existing answers**: there are several questions and answers ([1](https://superuser.com/questions/457020/openvpn-only-route-a-specific-ip-addresses-through-vpn), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/854194/openvpn-route-only-specific-subnetwork-through-vpn-works-for-single-ip-adress)) which address this exact problem but they do not work for me.

**Details**:

The setup is on Debian 8. I have an OpenVPN connexion on `10.8.8.134` (peered with a remote `10.8.8.133`) through which I would like to route traffic from `192.168.10.10`.

`192.168.10.10` is a manually created IP on `eth0`, which also receives via DHCP an address (`192.168.0.107`) and a default route (`192.168.1.1`).

I set up OpenVPN to

- refuse routes from the server (`--route-noexec`)
- remove the "fake default route" added by OpenVPN (two ranges covering all IPV4)
- add routing to `10.8.8.1/255.255.255.255` (OpenVPN server gw) via `10.8.8.133` (the assigned OpenVPN address)

In order to force traffic from `192.168.10.10` to go through the VPN I tried to

- `ip route add 192.168.10.10 dev tun0`
- or `ip route add 192.168.10.10 via 10.8.8.133`

The resulting routing table

```
root@debian-testing:~# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
10.8.8.1 via 10.8.8.133 dev tun0
10.8.8.133 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.8.134
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.107
192.168.10.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.10.10
```

The extra route is equivalent to using `route 192.168.10.10 255.255.255.255` in the OpenVPN config file.

In both cases running

```
traceroute -s 192.168.10.10 www.google.com
```

sends the packets to the real default gateway:

```
root@debian-testing:~# traceroute -s 192.168.10.10 www.google.com
traceroute to www.google.com (173.194.112.20), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
```

As seen by `tcpdump` (and wireshark)

[image]

Why doesn't this routing work?