# OpenVpn on router need assistance with single device bypass

Tags: router, home-networking, openvpn

I have a VPN on my router I was wondering if there was a certain configuration or changes I can make on my Asus router in order to have just my PS4 bypass the Vpn and everything else in my network to use the vpn.If there is a way besides using two routers please let me know or a specific model of router that can do something like this.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/457020/openvpn-only-route-a-specific-ip-addresses-through-vpn read through the answers here one of these may help you out.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but quite an advanced topic, and not available in all routers.     You may be able to do it with a router which uses OpenWRT and DD-WRT, but the fun part is the routing - you will need to do [policy based routing](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Policy_Based_Routing) (ie have the PS4 on a static IP address and have a separate routing table for the PS4).

There are [lots of devices](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices) which work with DD-Wrt.