# Allow only traffic to specific IP ranges to go through VPN

Tags: windows, networking, routing, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN on Windows. I have followed the instruction from this question [OpenVPN: Only route a specific IP addresses through VPN?](https://superuser.com/questions/457020/openvpn-only-route-a-specific-ip-addresses-through-vpn) to be able to route traffic to a single IP or an entire subnet through the VPN.

```
route-nopull 
route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

However, is it possible for me to route traffic to a range of IP addresses, for example only traffic that destined to IP `192.168.0.200` to IP `192.168.0.255` only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A route is working with network/netmask only. A range can be expressed by an union/sum of networks/netmasks. So:

```
192.168.0.200:192.168.0.255
```

is equivalent to the union/sum of:

```
192.168.0.200/255.255.255.248
192.168.0.208/255.255.255.240
192.168.0.224/255.255.255.224
```

Your new piece of configuration should become:

```
route-nopull
route 192.168.0.200 255.255.255.248
route 192.168.0.208 255.255.255.240
route 192.168.0.224 255.255.255.224
```

The (*nix) tool used to easily calculate those ranges was [netmask](https://github.com/tlby/netmask).